# Is there a way to mark EXCLUDE as UNIQUE constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I want to use `EXCLUDE` constraint in `FOREIGN KEY`.

Is there a way to mark `EXCLUDE` as `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

But I cannot think of a data type that would work with GiST indexes, but not allow b-tree indexes, so you could just create an additional `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: may you please provide an example how to create additional `UNIQUE` constraint? I have found that [GiST does not support unique](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-unique-checks.html) Also found that we [can query `can_unique` from index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-INDEXAM-PROPS) But do not know how to write this query. Data time with GiST `Create type bitemporal ( id int, period tstzrange )`

Comment: For example `ALTER TABLE bitemporal ADD UNIQUE (id, period);`

Comment: Then you have not described your issue well. Please [edit] the question and give us more details.